# Printing out the output in separate lines in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to print out the output of the maximum route each in a separate line.

The code is here:

```
def triangle(rows):
    PrintingList = list()
    for rownum in range (rows ):     
        PrintingList.append([])
        newValues = map(int, raw_input().strip().split())
        PrintingList[rownum] += newValues
    return PrintingList

def routes(rows,current_row=0,start=0): 
        for i,num in enumerate(rows[current_row]): 
            if abs(i-start) > 1:   
                continue
            if current_row == len(rows) - 1: 
                yield [num]
            else:
                for child in routes(rows,current_row+1,i):
                    yield [num] + child

testcases = int(raw_input())
output = []
for num in range(testcases):
    rows= int(raw_input())
    triangleinput = triangle(rows)
    max_route = max(routes(triangleinput),key=sum)
    output.append(sum(max_route))

print '\n'.join(output)
```

I tried this:

```
2
3
1
2 3
4 5 6
3
1
2 3 
4 5 6
```

When i try to output out the value, i get this:

```
print '\n'.join(output)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
```

How do change this? Need some guidance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
print '\n'.join(map(str, output))
```

Python can only join strings together, so you should convert the ints to strings first. This is what the `map(str, ...)` part does.

Comment: There's no difference between printing an integer and converting it to a string first then printing it (like in my example). When you print an integer it gets converted to a string behind the scenes anyway.

Answer (score 2):

@grc is correct, but instead of creating a new string with newlines, you could simply do:

```
for row in output:
    print row
```